# how to change multiple header into a flat header dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my data:

```
                            My Very First Column                        
Sr No           Col1                                      Col2      
Sr No   sub_col1    sub_col2    sub_col3    sub_col1    sub_col2    sub_col3
1        9             45         3           9           97          9
2        32            95         12          67          78          34
3        3              6         5           85          54          99
4        32            31         75          312         56          98
```

This is how I want it to be:

```
Sr No   Col1-sub_col1   Col1-sub_col2   Col1-sub_col3   Col2-sub_col1   Col2-sub_col2   Col2-sub_col3
  1            9             45               3               9              97               9
  2            32            95               12              67             78              34
  3            3             6                5               85             54              99
  4            32            31               75              312            56              98
```

The problem is the columns and sub columns always differ every time. Thus, I can't put any constant value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have a `dataframe` named `df`:-

Try using:-

```
columns=[]
for x in df.columns.to_list():
    columns.append('-'.join([list(x)[0],list(x)[1]]))
```

Finally:-

```
df.columns=columns
```